# Buscar 2 ocorrências no powershell

Tags: powershell

Como posso fazer para que encontrar 2 ocorrências juntas num determinando arquivo usando o powershell?

```
$p = @("string1","string2")
get-content C:\log.txt | Select-String -Pattern $p
```

Acima, a expressão me retorna as ocorrências que tenham uma string **OU** a outra. Não é o que quero, quero tenham uma string **E** a outra.

Quais são as maneiras de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

da pra fazer isso assim

```
get-content C:\log.txt | Select-String -Pattern "string1" |  Select-String -Pattern "string2"
```

Não sei se existe uma forma melhor

Answer (score 1):

> - Para proposta de exemplificar a resposta, substituí **`String1/String2`** adicionando <strike>**String3**</strike> :

---

> **String1** --> **pizza**
>
> **String2** --> **chocolate**
>
> <strike>**String3**</strike> --> **refrigerante**

---

- O que me atende para esse tipo de tarefa:

---

```powershell
$i=@('.+(?=.*\bpizza\b)(?=.*\brefrigerante\b)(?=.*\bchocolate\b).*'); gc .\log.txt | sls $i
```

---

> - Alguns exemplos ***diversificados*** aplicados nas buscas variadas em   **<kbd>[`PowerShell`](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/PSPunctuationWallChart_1_0_4.pdf)</kbd>**

---

```powershell
       # -------------------------------------------------------------------- #
       # listar o conteúdo do arquivo: .\log.txt                              #
         gc .\log.txt                                           # linha 0 - 8 #
       # -------------------------------------------------------------------- #
       # qualquer ocorrência de pizza, ou, refrigerante, ou chocolate         #
         gc .\log.txt | sls '(pizza|refrigerante|chocolate)'    # linha 1 - 8 #
         gc .\log.txt | sls 'pizza','refrigerante','chocolate'  # linha 1 - 8 #
         gc .\log.txt | sls 'chocolate','refrigerante','pizza'  # linha 1 - 8 #
         gc .\log.txt | sls 'refrigerante','chocolate','pizza'  # linha 1 - 8 #
         gc .\log.txt | sls '(?:pizza|refrigerante|chocolate)'  # linha 1 - 8 #
         gc .\log.txt | sls '(?:refrigerante|chocolate|pizza)'  # linha 1 - 8 #
         gc .\log.txt | sls '(?:chocolate|refrigerante|pizza)'  # linha 1 - 8 #
       # -------------------------------------------------------------------- #
       # chocolate | pizza | refrigerante numa ordem de ocorrências definida  #
       gc .\log.txt | sls 'chocolate.+pizza.+refrigerante'      # linha   - 7 #
       gc .\log.txt | sls 'refrigerante.+chocolate.+pizza'      # linha   - 8 #
       # -------------------------------------------------------------------- #
       # pizza + refrigerante + chocolate em qualquer ordem na mesma linha    #
         $i=@('.+(?=.*\bpizza\b)(?=.*\brefrigerante\b)(?=.*\bchocolate\b).*') #
         gc .\log.txt | sls $i                                 # linha 7 - 8  #
       # -------------------------------------------------------------------- #
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- Para atender qualquer busca dentre mais de uma **string**
- Para atender qualquer busca em determinada ordem de ocorrência das **strings**
- Para atender qualquer busca em sem determinada ordem de ocorrência das **strings**

  ---

> - **Conteúdo** do arquivo: **.\log.txt**  (linha 0 - 8)

---

```powershell
0) frase sem torta de sanduíche com mandioquinha
1) frase com pizza de --------- com ------------
2) frase com ----- de chocolate com ------------
3) frase com ----- de --------- com refrigerante
4) frase com ----- de chocolate com refrigerante
5) frase com pizza de --------- com refrigerante
6) frase com pizza de chocolate com ------------
7) frase com chocolate de pizza com refrigerante
8) frase com refrigerante de chocolate com pizza
```

---

> - Para **qualquer ocorrência** de **pizza**, ou **refrigerante** ou **chocolate** na linha

---

```powershell
  gc .\log.txt | sls '(pizza|refrigerante|chocolate)'    # linha 1 - 8 #
  gc .\log.txt | sls 'pizza','refrigerante','chocolate'  # linha 1 - 8 #
  gc .\log.txt | sls 'chocolate','refrigerante','pizza'  # linha 1 - 8 #
  gc .\log.txt | sls 'refrigerante','chocolate','pizza'  # linha 1 - 8 #
  gc .\log.txt | sls '(?:pizza|refrigerante|chocolate)'  # linha 1 - 8 #
  gc .\log.txt | sls '(?:refrigerante|chocolate|pizza)'  # linha 1 - 8 #
  gc .\log.txt | sls '(?:chocolate|refrigerante|pizza)'  # linha 1 - 8 #
```

---

> - **Resulta:**

---

```powershell
1) frase com pizza de --------- com ------------
2) frase com ----- de chocolate com ------------
3) frase com ----- de --------- com refrigerante
4) frase com ----- de chocolate com refrigerante
5) frase com pizza de --------- com refrigerante
6) frase com pizza de chocolate com ------------
7) frase com chocolate de pizza com refrigerante
8) frase com refrigerante de chocolate com pizza
```

---

> - Para as **ocorrências** pré-definidas das **strings** na linha:
>
>   - Obedece a ordem de ocorrências definida: **chocolate + pizza + refrigerante**

---

```powershell
gc .\log.txt | sls 'chocolate.+pizza.+refrigerante'
```

---

> - **Resulta:**

---

```powershell
7) frase com chocolate de pizza com refrigerante
```

---

> - Para as **ocorrências** pré-definida das **strings** na linha:
>
>   - Obedece a ordem de ocorrências definida: **refrigerante + chocolate + pizza**

---

```powershell
gc .\log.txt | sls 'refrigerante.+chocolate.+pizza'
```

---

> - **Resulta:**

---

```powershell
8) frase com refrigerante de chocolate com pizza
```

---

> - Para **múltiplas Strings** em **qualquer ordem de ocorrência** na linha:

---

```powershell
# pizza + refrigerante + chocolate em qualquer ordem na mesma linha    #
  $i=@('.+(?=.*\bpizza\b)(?=.*\brefrigerante\b)(?=.*\bchocolate\b).*') #
  gc .\log.txt | sls $i                                 # linha 7 - 8  #
```

---

> - **Resulta:**

---

```powershell
7) frase com chocolate de pizza com refrigerante
8) frase com refrigerante de chocolate com pizza
```

---

Comment: Para mais informações sobre regex em [powershell/en](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/06/02/regular-expressions-with-powershell.aspx)